# PHP time (Hours and Minutes) not adding correctly

Tags: php, while-loop, strtotime

I'm not a professional developer, so please don't shoot me down if this is obvious...

I have a table in a database and I need to sum to totals of time from a column in hours, minutes and seconds. I need the calculations to happen in PHP for further use after this transaction.

My time in the database is formatted like this:

```
01:30:00
01:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

My code is like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set(UTC);
while($sql_row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)){
$time = $sql_row['time'];
$total_time = strtotime("1970-01-01 ".$time)+strtotime("1970-01-01 ".$total_time);

echo date('H:i:s',$total_time)."<BR>";
    }

echo date('H:i',$total_time);
```

The problem is the out put shows its not adding at all for the first two rows. Then for all rows that are input with 00:00:00 i get 12:00:00 like this.
01:00:00
01:30:00
12:00:00
12:00:00

I have fiddled with it a thousand ways, and think it's something to do with the unix timestamp being +11/12 hours from my local time. (GMT). I have tried using date_default_timezone_set(UTC) but I then get the same result. I'm expecting to see this looped value repeat on 02:30:00 since the last values should not add anything to the value.

To test this without the loop I have tried this:

```
date_default_timezone_set(UTC);
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$time1 = "01:00:00";
$time2 = "01:30:00";
$time3 = "00:00:00";

$total = strtotime($date." ".$time1)+strtotime($date." ".$time2)+strtotime($date." ".$time3);

echo date('H:i:s',$total);
```

And this works fine! Some how I think the while loop is effecting it also but I cannot see any reference anywhere to adding time in while loops in PHP.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach using `date` and `stringtotime`.

I would have shot at the seconds. Something like...

```
$timings = array("01:30:00", "01:00:00", "60:00:00", "26:00:11");
$total_seconds = 0;
foreach ($timings as $time) 
{
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time);
    $total_seconds += $seconds + ($minutes * 60) + ($hours * 60 * 60);
}

$format     = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($total_seconds / 3600), ($total_seconds / 60 % 60), $total_seconds % 60); 
$as_date    = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $total_seconds);

echo "total seconds: ".$total_seconds ." | as date: ".$as_date." | formatted: ".$format;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ian, this worked. I guess I was coming at this from the wrong angle.

I had to amend the code slightly to use a while loop, because a foreach loop was only producing the first two values of the array.

Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

```
$total_seconds = 0;
while($testrow = mysqli_fetch_array($timings, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $testrow['time_dual']);
    $total_seconds += $seconds + ($minutes * 60) + ($hours * 60 * 60);
    echo $testrow['time_dual']."<br>";// For testing only
}

$format     = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($total_seconds / 3600), ($total_seconds / 60 % 60), $total_seconds % 60); 
$as_date    = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $total_seconds);

echo "total seconds: ".$total_seconds ." | as date: ".$as_date." | formatted: ".$format;
```